# How to make 7zip overwrite?

Tags: powershell, overwrite, 7zip

Does anybody had a problem overwriting files with 7zip. I use this script:

```
    if ($name.Contains('something'))
 {
 Get-ChildItem \\server\load\$name | 
 % {
 & "C:\test\7z.exe" "x" "-aoa" "-y" $_.fullname "-o\\server\output"
   }
  }
else
{
"$name unknown"
}
```

Everything works fine when you delete files before triggering script, but it wont overwrite new files. I use -aoa for that, but maybe there is different switch for that?
When i try to extract files on 7zip GUI and overwrite its fine also, so i guess it is not permission problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

`&"C:\test\7z.exe" x -aoa -y "$_.fullname" -o"\\server\output"`

The `&` is not very consistent with how it handles arguments, in my experience.  Generally, though, you should assume that PowerShell doesn't strip quotes from arguments when you use `&`.  You should only use quotes when the program you're calling needs them in it's own arguments.  In my script which archives IIS logs, I use this:

```
&"$7Zip" a "$ArchiveFile" "$FullLogPath\$LogFileSpec" -mx=9 -mmt=on
```

The variables are just path or file names.  The quotes are there simply because path and file names can have spaces in them.

The way I usually figure it out is by `Write-Host` the string that `&` is going to call, then copy and pasting it into a `cmd.exe` shell window

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunately your solution gives same result. Maybe I need to unzip files to another location and force move them?

Comment: Hm. That might work. The only thing I can think then is that it's an issue because the remote files are locked or just an issue with output to a remote path.  If the exact same line works when you enter it manually, though, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Today i watched if files are locked with script form this guy: http://mspowershell.blogspot.com.es/2008/07/locked-file-detection.html Before updating, files were not locked. stil same result. I think there is something wrong with 7zip, i will try another archive tool tomorrow.

Comment: I have had issues with it not impersonating the user correctly, particularly with UAC enabled.  If you try to view an image by double clicking it from within the archive with UAC enabled, 7-Zip loses track of the file.  You could try using `System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage` with Powershell 3.0+ if you're the type that needs things in actual PowerShell, or the Community Extensions at http://pscx.codeplex.com/ that includes a ZIP widget.

Comment: I think we can close this quesion. I will try your solutions. Also i'm thinking about renaming existing items before unziping, and after that deleting renamed files. It would be easiest workaround if that would work :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just as a point of order, here in April 2020, this is still a problem when running 7-Zip from PowerShell.  It simply will not overwrite files without first deleting them.  I don't know why, and this question did not resolve it.